# Restrict Maximum Elements inside Div - FIFO Streaming Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

My scenario is I am streaming data into rows to display inside a div.

So for each line I receive I am creating a span, then appending it.

However I wish to restrict the div to a maximum of 100 lines / span elements.

So if I receive new data, the oldest element is deleted to make space for the new element.

Any tips on how to implement this through jquery?

This is my current code, just appending.

```
dlogsocket.onmessage = function (event) {
    $("#ws-dlog-data").append(event.data);
};
```

Comment: please show what you did by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for element children number and if it is already 100, remove the first one before appending the new one:

```
dlogsocket.onmessage = function (event) {
   var $container = $("#ws-dlog-data");
   while ($container.children().length >= 100)
      $container.children().first().remove();
   $("#ws-dlog-data").append(event.data);
};
```

Comment: Thanks! `children().length` and `children().first()` is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You have to count how many element are present and remove the first, which should be the oldest, using [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/).

```
dlogsocket.onmessage = function (event) {
  $("#ws-dlog-data").append(event.data);

  // If more than 100 spans, remove the first (oldest).
  if( $("#ws-dlog-data span").length >100 ){
    $("#ws-dlog-data span").first().remove();
  }
};
```